# XmlSchema loses its content in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an `XmlSchema` that is instantised as a singleton.

```
public static XmlSchema MessageSchema
{
    get
    {
        lock (MessageSchemaLock)
        {
            // If this property is not initialised, initialise it.
            if (messageSchema == null)
            {
                // Read XSD from database.
                string xsd = Database.Configuration.GetValue("MessageBaseXsd");
                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xsd))
                {
                    messageSchema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, (sender, e) => {
                        if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error) throw e.Exception;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        // Return the property value.
        return messageSchema;
    }
}
private static XmlSchema messageSchema = null;
private static readonly object MessageSchemaLock = new object();
```

This schema is used to validate every document that enters the system.  The following method performs the validation.

```
/// <summary>
/// Validates the XML document against an XML schema document.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xml">The XmlDocument to validate.</param>
/// <param name="xsd">The XmlSchema against which to validate.</param>
/// <returns>A report listing all validation warnings and errors detected by the validation.</returns>
public static XmlSchemaValidationReport Validate(XmlDocument xml, XmlSchema xsd)
{
    XmlSchemaValidationReport report = new XmlSchemaValidationReport();

    xml.Schemas.Add(xsd);
    xml.Validate((sender, e) => { report.Add(e); });
    xml.Schemas.Remove(xsd);

    return report;
}
```

The `XmlSchemaValidationReport` contains a 'List' and some helper methods, nothing that ever sees the `XmlSchema` object.

When I validate messages on multiple threads, the `Validate` method fails after the first few messages have been processed.  It reports that one of the elements is missing, despite me seeing it clear as day.  My test is sending the same message several times, each as a separate `XmlDocument`.  I have double-checked that the `MessageSchema` property is the only code that ever sets the `messageSchema` field.

Is the `XmlSchema` somehow being altered during validation?  Why is my validation failing?

Comment: What do you mean, "loses its content"? Do you mean that it becomes `null`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've made a mistake there.  I thought it was nulling the non-public `document` field, but it turns out that's null from the beginning.  What I mean is it stops working despite the messages being the same.  I've edited above.

Comment: That's much better. Now all you need to do is tell us what "it stops working" means :-)

Comment: Validation passes on the first few runs.  After that is suddenly declares that a required element is missing.  I can see the element clear as day on the input.  It seems to be the 4th element each time, but that may just be a fluke.

Comment: is it the same XML/XSD each time?  or do either/both change?  Can you post both?  Maybe the problem is the XML or XSD?

Comment: There is only one instance of the `XmlSchema` object.  Each `XmlDocument` is a unique instance of the same XML.  The `XmlSchema` is added to each `XmlDocument`.

Comment: I observe that the documentation for the XmlSchema class says "Any public static members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." I'm afraid I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @MichaelKay: That means that it's necessary to prevent simultaneous access to any of the instance members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all of the comments and MiMo's answer!  They led me to a solution.

It seems that while I'm not calling any of the `XmlSchema` public members, the `XmlDocument.Validate()` method is.  The `XmlSchema` object contains state information that is not thread safe.

I changed the `MessageShema` to a per-thread singleton.

```
public static XmlSchema MessageSchema { ... }
[ThreadStatic]
private static XmlSchema messageSchema;
```

It loads the schema a few more times than I'd rather, but it works now.  This also meant I could drop the `MessageSchemaLock` as the value now cannot be accessed by multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

`XmlSchema` class is not thread-safe - I am not sure if the validation tries to modify it, but from the problem reported it appears to be the case. You could try

```
public static XmlSchemaValidationReport Validate(XmlDocument xml, XmlSchema xsd) 
{ 
    XmlSchemaValidationReport report = new XmlSchemaValidationReport(); 

    lock (xsd) {
      xml.Schemas.Add(xsd); 
      xml.Validate((sender, e) => { report.Add(e); }); 
      xml.Schemas.Remove(xsd); 
    }
    return report; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I see how that would work in my situation.  Unfortunately, that would defeat the parallel nature of my service.